# Controlling the width and height of a System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am using a Microsoft chart (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart).
In some cases, I make the height of the chart very tall (say around 5000px).  This is to handle lots of data.

The image has a lot of space where the top and bottom axis are.

I have set the position of the chart area to be (0, 0) and the height and width of the chart area to be 100%.  When I disable the AxisY2, the chart is drawn right at the top of the image.  When I enable it, there is a large area dedicated to the axis itself.  Any chart axis ticks would also be stretched (if I hadn’t set them to 0%).

I cannot figure out if it is possible to control the height and width dedicated to the axes.

My code so far:

```
Chart1.Height = 5000;
Chart1.Width = 500;
Chart1.BackColor = Color.Blue;

Random random = new Random();
var series = new Series();

for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 200; pointIndex++)
{
    series.Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(45, 95), 0));
}

series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
series.ChartArea = "chart-area1";

var area = new ChartArea("chart-area1");
area.Position.X = 0f;
area.Position.Y = 0f;
area.Position.Height = 100f;
area.Position.Width = 100f;
area.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
area.AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Size = 0;
area.AxisY2.MinorTickMark.Size = 0;

Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(area);
Chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

I testing on an aspx page, which has a tag:

```
<asp:CHART id="Chart1" runat="server" />
```

Thanks for any help